# Is it possible to use TomTom WebSdk MapTiles in raster mode?

Tags: maps, tomtom

I am using TomTom webSDK map tiles which by default work in vector mode:

https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-web-js/overview/product-information/introduction

Unfortunatelly it works very slow due to high CPU utilization. Is it possible to switch to raster mode, so it will serve map images like google maps does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example there:

```
var endpoint = 'https://{cyclingHostname}.api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/' +
               'main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?tileSize=512&key=<your-tomtom-maps-API-key>';
var tiles = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].map(function(hostname) {
    return endpoint.replace('{cyclingHostname}', hostname);
});
var map = tt.map({
    key: '<your-tomtom-maps-API-key>',
    container: 'map',
    style: {
        'version': 8,
        'sources': {
            'raster-tiles': {
                'type': 'raster',
                'tiles': tiles,
                'tileSize': 256
            }
        },
        'layers': [
            {
                'id': 'raster-tiles-layer',
                'type': 'raster',
                'source': 'raster-tiles'
            }
        ]
    },
    dragPan: !isMobileOrTablet()
});
map.addControl(new tt.FullscreenControl());
map.addControl(new tt.NavigationControl());
```